# Django Nextjs webscoket connecting can't established and getting 404 error

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, websocket, channel

I am trying to build an real time chat app so using django channel but I can't build web socket connect with my django and nextjs app.

my folder and file structure

```
backend
  ->backend
       ->settings.py
       ->wsgi.py
       ->routing.py
       ->consumers.py
```

my code:
**settings.py**

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = "backendfb.routing.application"

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND':  'channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer',
         
    },
}
```

**routing.py**

```
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.urls import path
from backendfb.consumers import TextRoomConsumer

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket': URLRouter(
        [
            path('ws/<room_name>/', TextRoomConsumer.as_asgi())
        ]
    ),
})
```

**consumers.py**

```
# backendfb/consumers.py

import json
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer

class TextRoomConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = f"chat_{self.room_name}"

        # Join room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        # Send message to room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat.message',
                'message': message
            }
        )

    async def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']

        # Send message to WebSocket
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))
```

**wsgi.py**

```
import os
from backendfb.routing import application

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'backendfb.settings')

application = application
app = get_wsgi_application()
```

my fontend code

```
   const client = new WebSocket(`ws://localhost:8000/ws/${Room}/`);
```